# How to download multiple documents at once using powershell only specific document ids

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell

i have a dcoument library in sharepoint record center application ,
enabled a document id for this web application ,
and in this document library users uploaded lot of documents  2000.

and here i need to download documents only related to some specific Document IDs ,
 in excel sheet i have bumch of Docuemnt IDs this number is 200.
here instead of download thos 200 documents one by one can i have other way to download documents 
that i have specific 200 document ids